# Composite C1 - Adding secondary navigation

Tags: c1-cms

I am enjoying Composite C1 CMS - though am having problems finding many tutorials.

I need some pages to have a secondary navigation.

I am also using the Composite.Community.Blog - which is working. It shows a preview of all blog posts & you click for details.

Instead I would like a subnavigation for this too on the left. When users click a blog post they're taken to the item.

What code do I need for the blog navigation - and general secondary navigation on other pages?

Also, any good tutorials or comprehensive sample sites (using blog a bonus) you can recommend i download anywhere would be very helpful (ones on composite site are very basic).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

niico,
1) To have secondary navigation please use Composite.Navigation.Distributed package (you need Level parameter).

Please read documentation about this package [here](http://www.composite.net/Add-on-Market/Packages/Composite.Navigation.Distributed.Razor/UserManual)

2) Demo sites automatically install during Composite C1 4.0 install. You can check demo site with blog online here http://demo.c1.composite.net
To have custom blog navigation here you can create your own version of [Blog Renderer](http://c1packages.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Composite.Community.Blog/Composite.Community.Blog.Package/Package/App_Data/Razor/Composite/Community/Blog/BlogRenderer.cshtml) function.
You will find full blog source there.